# Is there any way to get nearest public IPs by entering zip code

Tags: ip, ip-address, public, zipcode

I have a landing page and I want to get the closest IP address to a zipcode whenever I type in the customer's zipcode.

Jornaya is integrated into the landing page which captures whenever customer lands on the page and once the form is submitted. And IP address will generated, and I want that IP to be closes to that zip code.

Can anyone help me in this regard as to what I have to do to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a proxy server, search for one who provide target based proxy like i.e brightdata etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).